# Why only my Ubuntu laptop can not connect(wireless)?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking

All the people(with Windows OS) can connect to wireless router in my town's coworking space except me. I can detect it and I put the right password.

```
ip link
```

shows

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 54:e1:ad:05:7d:c4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp58s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:28:f8:85:ca:a4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I will add various nmcli ouputs

```
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE  
docker0             b9f97e97-0376-4a98-bed4-b396fdc1f364  bridge    docker0 
HH41V_7CF9          34d2521f-5e28-4623-af29-e08fd02fc1d5  wifi
```

--

device show

```
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         docker0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           bridge
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         02:42:5F:31:2C:11
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     docker0
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         172.17.0.1/16
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 172.17.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 0
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp58s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:28:F8:85:CA:A4
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          50 (connecting (configuring))
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     HH41V_7CF9
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/19

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         p2p-dev-wlp58s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi-p2p
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         (unknown)
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s31f6
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         54:E1:AD:05:7D:C4
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         lo
GENERAL.TYPE:                           loopback
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:00:00:00:00:00
GENERAL.MTU:                            65536
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         127.0.0.1/8
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         ::1/128
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = ::1/128, nh = ::, mt = 256

docker0: connected to docker0
    "docker0"
    bridge, 02:42:5F:31:2C:11, sw, mtu 1500
    inet4 172.17.0.1/16
    route4 172.17.0.0/16
    route4 169.254.0.0/16

wlp58s0: connecting (configuring) to HH41V_7CF9
    "Intel 8265 / 8275"
    wifi (iwlwifi), 00:28:F8:95:CA:A4, hw, mtu 1500

p2p-dev-wlp58s0: disconnected
    "p2p-dev-wlp58s0"
    wifi-p2p, hw
```

This what journalctl shows

```
journalctl -fu NetworkManager
-- Logs begin at Wed 2022-03-16 21:20:31 CET. --
апр 07 11:30:00 jb-ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[707]: <info>  [1649323800.9330] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
апр 07 11:30:00 jb-ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[707]: <info>  [1649323800.9381] device (p2p-dev-wlp58s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
апр 07 11:30:01 jb-ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[707]: <info>  [1649323801.1137] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
апр 07 11:30:01 jb-ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[707]: <info>  [1649323801.1137] device (p2p-dev-wlp58s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
апр 07 11:30:02 jb-ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[707]: <info>  [1649323802.1137] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
апр 07 11:30:02 jb-ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[707]: <info>  [1649323802.1138] device (p2p-dev-wlp58s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
апр 07 11:30:03 jb-ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[707]: <info>  [1649323803.2313] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
апр 07 11:30:03 jb-ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[707]: <info>  [1649323803.2313] device (p2p-dev-wlp58s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
апр 07 11:30:03 jb-ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[707]: <info>  [1649323803.3248] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
апр 07 11:30:03 jb-ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[707]: <info>  [1649323803.3255] device (p2p-dev-wlp58s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
апр 07 11:30:08 jb-ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[707]: <info>  [1649323808.3299] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
апр 07 11:30:08 jb-ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[707]: <info>  [1649323808.3300] device (p2p-dev-wlp58s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
апр 07 11:30:13 jb-ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[707]: <info>  [1649323813.9079] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
апр 07 11:30:13 jb-ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[707]: <info>  [1649323813.9080] device (p2p-dev-wlp58s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
апр 07 11:30:13 jb-ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[707]: <info>  [1649323813.9962] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
апр 07 11:30:13 jb-ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[707]: <info>  [1649323813.9964] device (p2p-dev-wlp58s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
апр 07 11:30:22 jb-ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[707]: <warn>  [1649323822.9591] device (wlp58s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
апр 07 11:30:22 jb-ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[707]: <info>  [1649323822.9592] device (wlp58s0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
апр 07 11:30:22 jb-ThinkPad-T470s NetworkManager[707]: <info>  [1649323822.9607] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
```

How to check if something is wrong with my wpa-supplicant(saw [problem with wifi connection on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1316988/problem-with-connection-to-wifi-on-ubuntu-20-04)?

Why? How to further inspect this?

Comment: What are the details or specs of the wireless network?

Comment: @music2myear Which command to detect that? nmcli?

Comment: @music2myear Can you take a look now?

Comment: Does it work with any other WIFI, e.g. from your home or your phone? You could start `journalctl -fu NetworkManager` before connecting and see what the logs reveal.

Comment: @eblock yes,it works from my home.

Comment: @eblock Can you take a look?

Comment: It appears that you choose a non-existing SSID: `failed (reason 'ssid-not-found'`. If you verified that it's the right SSID get in contact with administrator of the WIFI, maybe your device is on a blacklist or something (MAC filter).

Comment: @eblock I doubt about that.

Comment: That's fine, I'm just interpreting the logs you provided.

Comment: @eblock My admin friend suspects that Docker bridge is to blame. Is that possiblle?

Comment: Then it would be to blame for your home network, too, wouldn't it? But you could disable all other interfaces to rule that out. What is p2p-dev-wlp58s0?

Comment: @eblock I agree it doe not make sense. Regarding p2p-dev-wlp58s0,it popped out on nmcli device show,do not have idea.